# How to display milliseconds instead of microseconds with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In Django template language I can display a time with microseconds using :

```
{{ player.time_to_display|time:"i:s:u" }}
```

I would like to display only milliseconds instead of the full microsecond value. I am not able to locate a way to do that in the documentation, is there a simple mean to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in support for displaying milliseconds in Django, or in Python for that matter. Your best bet would be to implement a custom filter that accepts a datetime instance and do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What about dividing your microseconds by 1000 (and maybe round the new value off)?

1000 microsecons = 1 millisecond.

Comment: Ok I will go the route of implementing a new custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
{{ player.time_to_display|time:"i:s" }}:{{ player.time_to_display|time:"u"|slice:":3" }}
```

This separates milliseconds and takes just 3 first letters. However it does not do rounding - but do you really need it at such tiny values?

Comment: Careful - if you have less than 6 digits of microseconds, this won't give you milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this simple, but I think this will give you what you're looking for.

```
{{ player.time_to_display|time:'i:s' }}:{{ player.time_to_display|time:'u'|add:'0'|stringformat:'06i'|slice:':3' }}
```